# How to upload data from dataframe directly to Mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe

Currently I have a dataframe which contains more than 200 columns. Usually I create a csv and upload the data into the Mysql database in python.

Is there a way to directly upload a dataframe because the create table statement in this case would be over 200 lines!

Comment: Use `df.to_sql()`.

Comment: It requires SQLAlchemy and current version of Pandas does not support upload to mysql. Is there no alternative?

Comment: 200 columns can indicative of poor design

Comment: Thats another problem (related)